# Forward Kinematics Two fixed standard wheels

Tags: kinematics, wheel

[image]

What would the equations be for the robot's angular and linear velocity at P and also P2? I think I'm doing it wrong...

WL = left wheels angular velocity
WR = right wheels angular velocity

For P I had for example the linear velocity = (1/3)*r*WL + (2/3)*2r*WR

Am I on right track?

Comment: Can you explain that diagram?  If I'm reading it properly, it looks like the boxes on the outside are supposed to be the wheels, and the `r` and `2r` labels are radii (even though drawn as diameters).  Is that correct?

Comment: diameter. The below has examples of how this works, i just cant figure it out.
http://www.rose-hulman.edu/~berry123/Courses/ECE425/Spring07_files/Lecture2%20-%20Kinematics.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The linear velocity $v$ of a differential drive robot is the average of the velocities of its wheels [[^](http://omicsgroup.org/journals/dynamic-modelling-of-differentialdrive-mobile-robots-using-lagrange-and-newtoneuler-methodologies-a-unified-framework-2168-9695.1000107.pdf)]. In mathematical terms:

$$
v = \frac{v_L + v_R}{2}
$$

Where $v_L$ and $v_R$ are respectively the linear velocity of the left and right wheels. These are functions of their angular velocities and radii, such that:

$$
v_L = r_L \omega_L
$$

$$
v_R = r_R \omega_R
$$

Where $r_L$ and $r_R$ are respectively the radii (not the diameters!) of the left and right wheels, and $\omega_L$ and $\omega_R$ likewise the angular velocities.

The angular velocity $\omega$, on the other hand, is the average of the opposing contributions of left and right wheels: the left wheel contributes clockwise ("negative") motion, whereas the right wheel contributes counter-clockwise ("positive") motion. In mathematical terms:

$$
\omega = \frac{\phi_R - \phi_L}{2}
$$

Where the wheel contributions $\phi_L$ and $\phi_R$ are given by:

$$
\phi_L = \frac{r_L \omega_L}{l_L}
$$

$$
\phi_R = \frac{r_R \omega_R}{l_R}
$$

And $l_L$ and $l_R$ are respectively the left and right shaft lengths between the center of rotation and the left and right wheels.